# SQL equivalent of Excel's approximate VLOOKUP (first relevant value) without nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, nested

I am trying to find an efficient way to select the first relevant value from an existing table, as Excel's `VLOOKUP( , , , TRUE)` function would. Here is what I have, but if `@tableWithData` is very large compared to `@requiredDates`, this code can be very inefficient. I feel like I am missing something. Is there a better way of writing this:

```
DECLARE @requiredDates TABLE
(requiredDate datetime)
INSERT INTO @requiredDates VALUES ('2014-01-01');
INSERT INTO @requiredDates VALUES ('2014-01-15');
INSERT INTO @requiredDates VALUES ('2014-02-01');
INSERT INTO @requiredDates VALUES ('2014-02-15');

DECLARE @tableWithData TABLE
(respectiveDate datetime,
associatedValue int
)
INSERT INTO @tableWithData VALUES ('2014-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO @tableWithData VALUES ('2014-02-01', 2);

SELECT
    lookupTable.requiredDate,
    dataTable.associatedValue
    FROM @tableWithData as dataTable RIGHT JOIN
    (
    /*Create table which maps the requiredDates -> maxDate highest available date */
    SELECT
        dates.requiredDate,
        MAX(data.respectiveDate) as maxDate/*,
        data.associatedValue*/
        FROM @requiredDates as dates JOIN @tableWithData as data
        ON dates.requiredDate >= data.respectiveDate
        GROUP BY dates.requiredDate
    ) as lookupTable
    on lookupTable.maxDate = dataTable.respectiveDate
```

Note: I am using MS Server 2005, but would also appreciate a more generic SQL implementation, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, `vlookup()` with a value of "TRUE" finds an approximate match.  I am finding your query a bit hard to follow, but the following will get the largest value less than or equal to the `respectiveDate` field:

```
SELECT dt.associatedValue,
       (SELECT TOP 1 rd.requiredDate
        FROM dates.requiredDate rd
        WHERE rd.requiredDate <= dt.respectiveDate
        ORDER BY rd.requiredDate DESC
       ) as RequiredDate
FROM @tableWithData dt;
```

This structure for the query will work in all databases, with the caveat that `TOP 1` probably needs to be replaced with something else (a `limit` clause, a `fetch first 1 rows only` clause, or something else).  Of course, temporary tables will not.

In SQL Server, you can also express this using `APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this then realised that for the type of data I had there was a very simple answer and although it does not quite match your problem you might find it useful. Imagine the query you are trying to run is who was the reigning monarch on a given date and you have a table of the reigns of monarchs. In excel you would do a vlookup search on a sorted table of the start or end dates of the reigns but in SQL it is much easier to have  separate columns for reign-start and reign-end the query then is as simple as

SELECT * FROM 'monarchs' WHERE reign_start > date AND reign_end < date

As I said this is such a simple query that in some cases it might be worth seeing if the data could be reconfigured to allow it.